# Symfony Configuration - merge arrayNode default values with prototype

Tags: symfony, configuration-files

I need an array with defaults values, where I can overwrite them, and add new ones.
So far I got this:

```
$treeBuilder
    ->root('acme')
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('templates')
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('layout')->defaultValue('my-layout')->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                ->scalarNode('navbar')->defaultValue('my-navbar')->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
            ->end()
            ->prototype('scalar')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

By default the output array looks like this:

```
Array(
    [templates] => Array(
        [layout] => 'my-layout'
        [navbar] => 'my-navbar'
    )
)
```

I set my config like that

```
acme:
    templates:
        layout: my-new-layout
        foo: bar
        hello: world
```

---

**What I expect:**

```
Array(
    [templates] => Array(
        [layout] => 'my-new-layout'
        [navbar] => 'my-navbar'
        [foo] => 'bar'
        [hello] => 'world'
    )
)
```

**What I get:**

```
Array(
    [templates] => Array(
        [foo] => 'bar'
        [hello] => 'world'
    )
)
```

The prototype overwrites everything, what is the proper configuration?

Comment: Hi @AlexisWbr , have you found the answer?

Comment: I use a kind of workaround but still haven't found any solution @mmmm

Answer (score 0):

There is unnecesarry prototype inside array node. I have also added `addDefaultsIfNotSet()` to array node.

```
$treeBuilder
    ->root('acme')
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('templates')
            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
            ->ignoreExtraKeys()
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('layout')->defaultValue('my-layout')->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                ->scalarNode('navbar')->defaultValue('my-navbar')->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

Comment: Yes but without the protype() I can't add new values, like in my exemple `foo: bar` and `hello: world`. The error `InvalidConfigurationException - Unrecognized options "foo, hello" under acme.templates` is thrown

Comment: By doing this I simply cant add more values into the array